# How to create a String with all objects from a core data class

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

#### Explanation

In my app I want to add the ability to export the data of a member. Im talking about all the transactions of the member. This is what I have, I hope it's clear what I'm asking.
What do I have to edit, that it works? Or is my way the right?

```
var str: [String] = []
for trans in (member?.transactions!)! {
    let trnsctnr = trans.reason
    let trnsctna = String(trans.money)
    var trnsctnd = ""
    if let trnsd = trans.date{
        trnsctnd = dateFormatter.string(from: trnsd)
    }
    str = [trnsctnr, trnsctna, trnsctnd] as! [String]
}
```

This code doesn't work. I want to add this in a 'MFMailComposerController' and than this error is shown :

> Cannot convert value of type 'Never' to expected argument type 'String'

[image: Core Data Model]

So I want to export the data of all transactions which the member did.

What I did as a computed property:

```swift
struct stringForMFMail {
            let trnsctnr = transaction?.reason
            var trnsctna = ""
            if let trns  = transaction?.money {
                trnsctna = String(trns)
                
            }
            var trnsctnd = ""
            if let trnsd = transaction?.date{
                trnsctnd = dateFormatter.string(from: trnsd)
            }
            let dataString = [trnsctnr, trnsctna, trnsctnd]
            

            }
```

This doesn't work at all, so I'm sure I did it completely wrong. There are some errors like: Struct declaration cannot close over value 'self' defined in outer scope. Totally there are 12 error in this little part so I did something really wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "export", and why exactly do you need to re-express the data as a string? The data is already the data; what is the point of "exporting" it?

Comment: With exporting I mean, that I want to add this to a MFMailComposerController which I already have, so thats not important. What do you mean with re-express the data as a string?

Comment: Well, I think you've answered both questions. You really do want to re-express it as a string because you want the user to be able to mail a statement of some kind. That's fine. So what's the question exactly? Is the code that you showed not working somehow? "I hope it's clear what I'm asking." It isn't. "What do I have to edit, that it works?" Explain how it _doesn't_ "work". What do you get and how does that differ from what you desire?

Comment: No it doesnt work. If I add it to the messagebody of the mailcomposer, there is this error: `Cannot convert value of type ‘Never‘ to expected argument type ‘String`. So I think the type of str is wrong.

Comment: That's great. But do you notice anything? You didn't say that _anywhere_ in your question! If that's what the question is supposed to be about, _edit_ the question so that it _is_ what it's about! _Show_ how you "add it to the message body of the mail composer". You say "that is not important" but obviously it is _very_ important because that's where the problem is. We cannot _guess_ what the question is; you have to _tell_ us. Tell us the error. Show us the code where the error occurs and tell us which line it occurs on. That is how to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Add a computed property in `Transaction` (I could not resist to fix the typo) for example `stringRepresentation` to compose the string you need. Then call `member.transactions.map{ $0.stringRepresentation }` to get an array of those strings. `join` them to one string if necessary.

Comment: Okay, I already corrected the typo, it is an older screenshot but since there where so edits I used it again. :D

Comment: But I have a question for your answer: What is a computed property? I know this might be a very dumb question, but since this is my first app as a project for school Im not really into those special words.

Comment: Please read the section *Computed Properties* in [Swift Language Guide - Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

Comment: @vadian I tried it. I think I did something completely wrong but I don't know what. Can you give me some advice please?

Comment: I added the things I did to the question

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class `Transaction` add this computed property, it returns the three values – if present – comma separated.

```
var stringForMFMail : String {
     var result = self.reason ?? "" 
     result += "\(self.money)"

     if let trnsd = self.date {
        result += ", \(dateFormatter.string(from: trnsd))"
     }
     return result
}
```

Add also this date formatter in `Transaction`

```
let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd:MM:yyyy"
    return formatter
}()
```

Now you can populate the array

```
var mailStrings = [String]()
if let transactions = member?.transactions {
   mailStrings = member.transactions.map{ $0.stringForMFMail }
}
```

If you need one single string, `join` the array

```
let str = mailStrings.join(separator: ", ")
```

Comment: Great, I really appreciate your work. I added the computed property to the class and got these errors: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Double' , in the line if let tans = self.money and the error Use of unresolved identifier 'dateFormatter'  in the line: result += ", \(dateFormatter.string(from: trnsd))" I tried it with DateFormatter with a capital D and then got this error : Instance member 'string' cannot be used on type 'DateFormatter'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: I fixed the *conditional binding* error. You have to copy also the date formatter instance used in your code into the `Transaction` class

Comment: Okay, it's getting closer and closer. There are now just two little mistakes in the text. The reason gets displayed like this: Optional("REASON") and the date is just nothing.

Comment: If there is always a reason write `"\(self.reason!)` or use optional bindings like for the date. I cannot help with the date because there is not enough information.

Comment: Okay thank you anyway, if you want to help me with the date, just tell me what information you need. You really helped me and I really appreciate your help

Comment: What is `date`? `Date` or maybe `String`. What date format do you want to convert the date to?

Comment: The Date is of type date, I want to convert it in dd:mm:yyyy if thats what you mean with convert.

Comment: Great man you are a hero. Is it possible to write each club on a different line or is this not possible? That‘s the last question for sure I bothered you too much .

Comment: `join(separator: "\n")`

Comment: I got now just /n instead of a new line :/

Comment: *Backslash* (`\\`) not slash (`/`). Isn't it ⇧⌥7 on the German keyboard?

Comment: Thank you another time I really really appreciate your work.